# Checking for Null values when accessing field values

Tags: c#

I am attempting to check a field value for null.

Assuming that item is a valid Outlook ContactItem, the following code, I would have thought, would have checked for a null value and returned "(Empty)" if the relevant field is null.

```
EntryID = item.EntryID.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
Title = item.Title.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
First_Name = item.FirstName.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
Middle_Name = item.MiddleName.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
Last_Name = item.LastName.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
Suffix = item.Suffix.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
Company = item.CompanyName.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
Home_Phone = item.HomeTelephoneNumber.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
Mobile_Phone = item.MobileTelephoneNumber.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
FirstLastName= item.LastNameAndFirstName.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
```

However, what is happening on other fields, is an error as follows:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The error is not a NullReferenceException in the strict sense - the error relates to the contacts field not the ContactItem object.

Now would I be right in saying that the error is actually telling me that the field is in fact an object, which if it does contain text, is removed from the ContactItem ?

I have attempted to mitigate the error, by filling in each field in an Outlook Contact - the error does not get thrown - but if I delete the field contents, of say CompanyName, the code will fail on that line with the same error.

If I am right, then how would I check if the object exists prior to trying to get the field contents?

MTIA

DWE

Comment: If `item` is null, accessing `item.EntryID` will cause this exception. If `EntryID` is null calling `item.EntryID.ToString()` will throw this exception, and so on, and so forth. Sichi's suggestion is good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the null-conditional operator.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Example:
If Property is null:

```
EntryID = item.EntryID?.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
```

If item is null:

```
EntryID = item?.EntryID.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
```

Or check both

```
EntryID = item?.EntryID?.ToString() ?? "(nothing)";
```

Comment: Hi Sichi, I didn't realise that you could coalesce as you have shown. Thank you.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, not true, if `item` is null then the conditional dereference will skip that member [and all the remaining dereferences in the chain](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBY4AcoQGYEsA2MAJgD4ACATAIwCwAUGQMwAElzAwvQN73N+ssyVAAzMAsgAoAKgFd0hADy4AdgBcAfMwQBKZgF5NCAPwA6AJKqYAWyompEAMqqoKgOYTtAbnoBfIA=).

Answer (score -2):

Try Using Ternary Conditional Operator

```
Condition ? True : False
```

If you are retriving data from Database then this

```
if(item.EntryID.ToString() == DBNull) ? item.EntryID.ToString() : "(nothing)";
```

And if still shows error then try to put **?** with datatype of EntryID

```
public string? EntryID;
```

Comment: `public string? EntryID;` will show an error. Nullable reference types won't be with us until C# 8. And i'm also fairly certain that calling `item.EntryID.ToString() == DBNull` will fail when `item` is null or `item.EntryID` is null.

Comment: You seem to be blending the conditional operator and the 'if' statement in unnatural ways. Also, comparing items based on their 'ToString' is bad practice and can lead to false positives, perhaps you meant `item.EntityID == DBNull.Value`?